# Create web services for Data Mining using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I am getting started with Data Mining for design an E-trading system that able to show recommendations for customers who have online trading. Depend on Market Basket (purchasing history), BIDS show the product that suitable for my recommendation I have designed all data mining structure and model good and success to query the result in BI

I have to develop on ASP.NET, objective-C (IOS) and android. I need to write a webservice using C# but i don't know how to query from BIDS. Does anybody know?

```
SELECT
  t.[CustomerKey],
  t.[Region],
  PredictAssociation([Association].[v Assoc Seq Line Items], include_statistics, 3)
From
  [Association]
PREDICTION JOIN
  SHAPE {
  OPENQUERY([Adventure Works DW],
    'SELECT
      [CustomerKey],
      [Region],
      [OrderNumber]
    FROM
      [dbo].[vAssocSeqOrders]
    ORDER BY
      [OrderNumber]')}
  APPEND 
  ({OPENQUERY([Adventure Works DW],
    'SELECT
      [Model],
      [OrderNumber]
    FROM
      [dbo].[vAssocSeqLineItems]
    ORDER BY
      [OrderNumber]')}
    RELATE
      [OrderNumber] TO [OrderNumber])
    AS
      [vAssocSeqLineItems] AS t
ON
  [Association].[v Assoc Seq Line Items].[Model] = t.[vAssocSeqLineItems].[Model]
ORDER BY t.[CustomerKey]
```

How to call this predictive query in C# and get result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume here that you know how to write a web service.

You should use the adomd.net to fetch your cube data.

Refer: [ADOMD.NET Client Programming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123477.aspx)

Example: [Displaying a grid using ADOMD.NET and MDX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28290/Microsoft-Analysis-Services-2005-Displaying-a-grid)

Code:

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(strConn);
conn.Open();
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(MDX_QUERY, conn);
CellSet cst = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();
```

Comment: The query you have posted is DMX. The good part is that you can use DMX queries too with Adomd. Just pass your query as string where I have passed `MDX_QUERY`